# PHP - XML to CSV conversion issue

Tags: php, xml, csv

I really need some help on an issue: I'm converting an XML to CSV using a PHP script, but the XML contains some + signs and I don't know how to remove them from the CSV.

This is the XML file structure:

```
<PRICES>
<PRICE>
<WIC>HDE0AAFGRBOX</WIC>
<STOCK>100+</STOCK>
<MY_PRICE>219.00</MY_PRICE>
</PRICE>
</PRICES>
```

This is the script I use:

```
<?
$filexml='stock.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('stock.csv', 'w')
foreach($xml->PRICES->PRICE as $price) {
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($price),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

The script works fine and the CSV file is good, but because I'm a noob with PHP I don't know how to remove the "+" sign.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume `<STOCK>100+</AVAIL>` is <STOCK>100+</STOCK>?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the `fopen` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to trim the chars you want to be removed (the '+' char):

```
foreach($xml->PRICES->PRICE as $price) {
   $price->STOCK = trim($price->STOCK, "+");
   fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($price),',','"');
}
```

Comment: Trim will only remove the + sign if it is at the beginning or end of the string, but this will probably be the case. Otherwise use `$price->STOCK = str_replace("+","",$price->STOCK);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use str_replace :

```
$filexml='stock.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('stock.csv', 'w')
foreach($xml->PRICES->PRICE as $price) {
$price->STOCK = str_replace("+","",$price->STOCK);
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($price),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
```