# XML to CSV = invalid Argument

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Hello I have the following xml results that are returned from a remote site

```
<ResultSet totalResultsAvailable="1">
  <Product orderNo="5321" partNo="A2345" truckable="1">
  <Manufacturer id="22">WIDGET 4 U</Manufacturer>
  <Model id="356">ACME 500</Model>
  <Years>95-98</Years>
  <ProductType id="23" categoryID="4">Cool Red Widgest</ProductType>
  <Material id="6">shiny stuff</Material>
  <PartNo>A2345</PartNo>
  <Code/>
</Product>
</ResultSet>
```

I am simply trying to pull  the xml results and place in a new csv file with the following code:

but I get and error: Warning:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/myServer/public_html/xmlParser2.php on line 14
```

Here is my code:

```
<?
echo 'Write XML to CSV';
$basenameLong ='http://thisIsTheURLto.com/myFeed/?key=123456789&mode=getProducts;
$fileNameCSV = 'xmlParseContent.csv';

$feedContent = '';    
echo '<br/>Starting......';     
$feedContent = file_get_contents($basenameLong);

$fh = fopen($fileNameCSV, 'w+'); //create new CSV file if not exists else append

foreach($feedContent->ResultSet->Product as $product) {

    fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($product),',','"');
}
fclose($fh);


?>
```

I know this code is very elementary but can you help me find the issue. I am a novice and I dont see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong :

```
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($product),',','"');
```

if you want to put blank values, try doing this :

```
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($product),'','','');
```

Comment: Well my goal is to create a a file for importing into excel with columns containing the data for the nodes like this:

OrderNo  |  partNO   | Manufacturer id  | Model  |  Years  | ProductType id  |  Product Type CategoryID   | Material  |  PartNo

Dont need the headers but just all the info in seprate columns or tab delimited or delimited with something crazy lik ~~^  so I can import. Trying to teach myself and I thought I was on the right track but failed right away on just this first part.

Comment: This is what I was using as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240393/php-xml-to-csv-conversion-issue

Comment: I found a few typos and fixed them but still have a problem. heres my new code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never parse your XML file. Replace `file_get_contents` with `simplexml_load_file` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP to convert XML to CSV is fairly easy, at least in the situations I've encountered so far. In my case, it would save me significant work if I could simply convert structured XML data into CSV data. Typically, I want to convert only the data in a particular xpath of the original XML document. The PHP function below will load an XML file and convert the elements in the specified xpath to simple csv data.

```
function xml2csv ($xmlFile, $xPath) {

    // Load the XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

    // Jump to the specified xpath
    $path = $xml->xpath($xPath);

    // Loop through the specified xpath
    foreach($path as $item) {

        // Loop through the elements in this xpath
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {

            $csvData .= '"' . trim($value) . '"' . ',';

        }

        // Trim off the extra comma
        $csvData = trim($csvData, ',');

        // Add an LF
        $csvData .= "\n";

    }

    // Return the CSV data
    return $csvData;

}
```